# Best ORM for finance domain app for MSSQL in node.js? TypeORM/Knex/ORM2 or Sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, node-orm2, typeorm

I am new to node.js, and developing an app with MSSQL i want faster ORM or framework which will be faster to query with sql db. I was checking TypeORM, it has beautify code structure and many more can i go for it?

Comment: The domain doesn't matter at all. It depends more on the kind of things technically your app should do. Anyway, Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask such a question. It's opinion based.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.